# Python - Mental Math Test (Can this be more efficient?)

Tags: python

I've been trying to improve my python skills and basically I decided to make this program that asks the user 10 simple math questions using only +, -, and /. My code works (well I have tested it and so far it does) but I want it to retain its current functionality. But is there a method to make this more efficient? It's Python 3.4.3

```
    import random

    username = input("Enter your name: ")
    score = 0

    for i in range(10):
        sign = ""
        answer = 0
        numOne = random.randint(1,10)
        numTwo = random.randint(1,10)
        pickOperator = random.randint(1,3)
        if pickOperator == 1:
            sign = " + "
            answer = numOne + numTwo
        elif pickOperator == 2:
            sign = " - "
            answer = numOne - numTwo
       elif pickOperator == 3:
            sign = " * "
            answer = numOne * numTwo
        else:
            print ("An error has occured")
        question = "What is " + str(numOne) + sign + str(numTwo) + "? "
        user_answer = int(input(question))
        if user_answer == answer:
            print ("That was the correct answer!")
            score = score + 1
        else:
            print ("That answer was incorrect!")

    print (username + " you got " + str(score) + " out of 10")
```

Comment: Hint: You can replace that `pickOperator` -> `sign`  `if...else` block with a tuple or list. You may get a few more ideas if you Google "python random maths quiz".

Answer (score 2):

Several things can be done to make your code more Pythonic, but note: efficiency (like running the code faster) will probably be the same because its speed is likely to be limited on how fast the user can input data and this is several magnitude orders slower than your computer's clock.

To be easy to expand your operations, you can create something like this:

```
from operator import add, sub, mul
signs = ['+', '-', '*']
operations = [add, sub, mul]
mapping = {s: o for s, o in zip(signs, operations)}
```

Therefore, you can use your `pickOperator` this way:

```
sign = signs[pickOperator]
operation = mapping[sign]
answer = operation(numOne, numTwo)
```

And remove all those `if`, `elif`.

When an invalid operation occurs, your `sign` assignment you will receive an exception (`IndexError`). So you have to catch it and display your error message to continue the program. Although this should never occur if you use your random functions correctly:

Consider using `randrange` instead of `randint`. So you will be able to write:

```
pickOperator = random.randrange(0, len(signs))
```

Another option is to just abandon this variable and use `random.choice` instead:

```
sign = random.choice(signs)
```